# System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control to display pdf

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, .net-2.0

Is there any way to query the state of an IE plugin (Adobe Reader)? I have a situation where we present many multi-page reports to users through an embedded browser (the preferred pattern based on my research) hosted by a tab page. When the user navigates away from the report, usually to modify the data, they return to  re-initialized Adobe Reader. This means their place was lost and expanded bookmark nodes have been collapsed.

Below is a simplified code snippet which I hope full expresses the nature of my problem.

```
Public partial class ReportView : UserControl
{ 
    private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser; 
    private MyNamespace.ReportGenerator reportGen;  
    private String currentPDFtempPath; 

    public ReportView() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Leave += (o, e) => { /*how can I save current place in pdf?*/ };
        this.Enter += (o, e) => { /*return user last place in large pdf*/ };
    }

    public void ViewReport(string reportName)
    {
        currentPDFtempPath = reportGen.GetReport(reportName);
        webBrowser.Navigate(currentPDFtempPath);
    }

    private void RefreshReport()
    {
        webBrowser.Navigate(currentPDFtempPath); /*reinitializes Adobe Reader*/
    }
}

public class ReportController
{
    private DataModel model;
    private ReportView view;

    ReportController(DataModel m, ReportView v)
    {
        this.model = m;
        this.view = v;

        model.Changed += (o, e) => { view.RefreshReport(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to see the point of this code.  Just remove the Enter event handler.

Comment: Reports need to be regenerated when changes are made to the model data. The real code handles it differently via controllers but I thought this was the most concise way to express the essence of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just call ViewReport to display another report.  The Enter event does not modify the model data so should *not* regenerate the report.

Comment: I revised the code based on your comment to provide a more accurate representation. There is a controller class, initially omitted for brevity, which modifies the model and updates the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your user base has standardized to one version of Acrobat or continuously updates to the latest and greatest Acrobat, an alternate solution is to eliminate the webbrowser control and add a reference to the AcroPDF/AxAcroPDF library/active x control, which works from a windows form.  I have used this in my company for the past 6 years and it has worked flawlessly.

Comment: The user base is very far from standardized, but I had considered bundling a specific version of Adobe Reader with my installation and using the active x control. Even though this would require a major rewrite, I had difficulty the API reference for the active x controls and I saw a comment on one thread that newer versions of Adobe Reader provided less support for this.